# Relative distance 3d cursor on the right axis

Tags: mesh, vertices, transforms, faces, 3d-cursor

I have a problem and i can't find a solution. I have a face on my object. I want to align a vertice so that vertice is on the same plane of the face.
I created  a Trasform Orentation on the face so that i have the right axis where to move on the vertice. I also set the 3d cursor but when i want to put z=0 the vertices doesn't align with the face. I know that the problem is the local origin but i can't find any other method. I can move the vertices put all coordinates to 0 and restore x and y but it's a very dirty way.
[image: 3D cursor on the face with right alignment]

[image: the vertice that i want to align with this face. if i put z=0 doesn't work]

[image]

Comment: Use snap to face option maybe and grab along the axis you've defined.

Comment: it's a good option for my purpose but it's not what i would like. I would that the cylinder has vertices on the plane without deform it

Comment: Hard to see clearly how things are on the pictures. Could you upload a blend file with the key elements in it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i added the blend file. There many of theese situation. I'm trying to make a non manifold object for 3dprint. I know that i can do this thing in some more dirty ways but i also want to do a nice job, just for learn.

Comment: Still not sure, I've understood what to move... the bottom vertex of the disk visible above the selected face in the first screenshot?

Comment: yes the vertex so that it has on the same plane of the face but moving along his own axis

Comment: So, the custom orientation should be from the edge/face on the disk part. Then set snap to face and grab the vertex along YY. Keys G to grab the Y and Y to go along the custom edge orientation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to snap all the vertices of the rim to the surface at once, you could assign them to a Vertex Group, temporarily <kbd>P</kbd> split the hatch off into a separate object, and give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, affecting only the vertex group, targeted on the surface.

[image]

If you align the hatch object-axes down the edge of interest,then you can use the modifier to project all the vertices in the desired direction. Apply the modifier, rejoin the objects.

Comment: You can take this further, and make [decals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162395/35559) of your attachments.